# Angular Component Background Color

Tags: html, css, angular, background-color

Good day everyone, i'm facing the whole page background-color problem and it didn't display the background color.

[Example Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHDjK.png)

```css
*{
    background-color: #7395AE !important
}
```

[Structure of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQKF5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this to css:

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #7395AE;
}
```